# Unable to read large XML file PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to parse data from an XML file of size nearly 10GB provided by a third party and they are daily updating the same file.

I need to parse the same and populate into MySql DB.

As per the research I found that XMLReader can handle this.

Tried some examples from Stackoverflow but was not working for this size.

Please share idea about chop the xml file into manageable pieces, then launch multiple importer "instances" in the cloud to process the individual files using PHP.

Comment: What exactly is not working with this? Are you getting any error messages? If you want to chop the file and import in chunks it may get tricky to keep it as valid XML, depending on the source.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response
This was the warning I was getting when I tried the huge file and was working fine with small files.
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Comment: DOMDocument !== XMLReader

Comment: When I tried to use **xml_parser** got this warning.
Warning: fopen(example.xml): failed to open stream: Value too large for defined data type in /xxx/index.php on line 56
could not open XML input

Comment: [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use SAX Parser with XPATH Query Processing.